# Memory Requirements of Shell Variable Assignment

Tags: shell, scripting, embedded-linux, busybox

I have a very resource limited system, where I have around 900kB of free memory and need to implement a script that reads from a local file, gets an IP address, and then pings it and looks for a response (to check that it is still on a working network).

The problem I have is not in the parsing of files or the passing of parameters, it's that when I attempt to use command substitution to create a variable to ping with, I can see the device freeze and it returns a SIGSEGV error code:

```
addrVar=`cat some_file_with_only_an_ip_address`
```

This seems like a trivial task, the parsing of a text file should be much more memory and processor intensive but it works fine. I can't seem to find any hints anywhere that have the same or similar issues. Does anyone have any idea why this doesn't work and possibly a solution?

The complete example code is:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -nr 's/IPADDR="([^ ]+)"/\1/p' /etc/config/net > tmpVarFile
var1=`cat tmpVarFile` #this fails, but not the above
```

Where tmpVarFile contains only an ip address

Thanks!

**Solution**

Please see @CharlesDuffy's answer below.

The best way to make this work was to read in the /etc/config/net file which was formatted like a set of shell variables (eg. `ipaddress="x.x.x.x"`) then simply use the following:

```
. /etc/config/net
if ping -c 1 ipaddress;
then
echo "Success"
else
echo "Failure"
fi
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Try avoiding the file entirely and just use `var1=$(sed ....)`?

Comment: I've tried that before, but just for fun I did it again, same result.  It's not sed, it's the 'var=`command`'. Also, the shell doesn't understand the $() substitution.  I'm using busybox and the minux shell from around 2004.

Comment: Are you sure this is a memory problem and not a ulimit/process problem? It sounds like the sub-shell might be the issue. Does `echo \`cat tmpVarFile\`` work? Does `echo \`echo blah\``?

Comment: FYI, `$()` is part of POSIX sh, so any shell without it is noncompliant with the standard. Modern busybox uses an ash derivative, which definitely has support.

Comment: @EtanReisner, both those commands work on their own, the problem is when they are used in a shell script.  Just using `var='sed -nr 's/IPADDR="([^ ]+)"/\1/p' /etc/config/net'` in my telnet session works fine, as soon as I place it in the script and run it, it causes a segfault.

Comment: Do the simpler versions also crash when in a script? This sounds awfully like your environment is just horrifically broken to me.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, that might be the case, but this system seems far from modern.  At any rate I get a syntax error.

Comment: @EtanReisner, thanks for the help, and yes the simpler versions do, I just tested that as well.  Putting 'echo 'cat tempVarFile`' into a script causes a segfault.  That's my opinion as well, but I thought perhaps I was just doing something dumb or misunderstood the system.  It's running on 2MB of flash so it's a very stripped down kernel.  Sounds like I might have to write a C program to accomplish this very simple task.

Comment: Hmm... If I kill the SNMP task running in the background I can free up 2.5MB RAM an the script works fine.  Unfortunately that's not doable, SNMP needs to be running all the time.  Still, 700+ kB seems like more than enough memory to create a subshell and copy a variable.

Comment: If your `cat` is provided by a statically linked busybox... well, how large is that binary? If you're not getting reuse through dynamic linking, that can be expensive. (Though I'd hope busybox would treat it as a builtin, we _are_ running an ancient vintage with limited capabilities).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an easy workaround here, since you only need to read one line:

```
read -r var1 <tempVarFile
```

This avoids use of any subprocesses altogether, substantially decreasing memory use (most of which will be associated with the `fork()` to start a subshell -- which wouldn't be too large on modern platforms doing copy-on-write, but it's hard to tell what ancient, tiny embedded platforms will do -- and the `fork()` again to run `/bin/cat`).

---

Alternately, if `/etc/config/net` is trusted, and guaranteed to be a valid shell script without unwanted side effects:

```
. /etc/config/net
if ping "$IPADDR"; then
  : ...etc...
fi
```

Comment: Hmm, well the busybox binary is 248548 bytes, so not too large.

I also get the following error: ��: cannot redirect shell command.  Not sure why this is...  I'm thinking perhaps I can avoid this by providing the IP address directly to the ping command and checking for a success from standard error $?.

Comment: Actually -- do you have memory overcommit enabled? Your system may not be allowing the copy-on-write of a fork if it doesn't have enough RAM to back it up if those pages are modified and need to be copied.

Comment: Such are the dangers of running a shell that doesn't meet POSIX-minimum functionality. Does it support `exec <tempVarFile` to redirect the shell's own stdin?

Comment: ...and yes, providing the address to ping is a good idea. No reason to look at `$?` explicitly; just `if ping ...; then ...; else ...; fi` will automatically check exit status.

Comment: If `/etc/config/net` is guaranteed to be a shell script, and trusted to be non-malicious, you could also `. /etc/config/net` to get its variables into your current shell.

Comment: I'm not sure about memory overcommit, I didn't build this kernel initially and I'm also not sure how to check for that.  This is actually the first I've heard of it, I'll have to read more about it.

Yes, I tried 'cat <tmpVarFile' which works fine.

Comment: Seems that even with this method I'm not able to run the script without a segfault.  I'm now doing as you suggested, ping `sed ARGs' and I'm still having issues running it.  Changing it do your way and reading in the /etc/config/net file is nothing short of brilliant, it works great!  I'll write up a brief answer above in a minute.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this problem has been driving me nuts for days now!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85148/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-fratink).